# How can one determine if all reagents will react in the reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reagents

[image]

Is it correct that all the reagents above the arrow will participate to form an intermediate product, to which the reagents below the arrow are then added, and they react to form the final product?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself . Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange. The reagents are there because they are critical to the success of the transformation.

Comment: Thank you... No, it isn’t homework question. And am not asking to get my question solved. I just need to understand when reagents will be considering for reaction. How to determine if a reagent take place within the reaction. It is just a general question. But i tried to upload this picture to explain my question and make it clear @user55119

Comment: One very important aspect about organic chemical reactions is their very detailed descriptions about reagents. Some of them are catalysts or inhibitors. Some of them are solvents. Some of them are acids or bases which provide an optimal medium for the reaction to happen. In your case, in the first step you perform the oxymercuration first and then the demercuration with sodium borohydride. Methanol is the polar solvent we need in this reaction. I suggest you read *"Robert B. Grossman - The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms"*.

Comment: Is there a list that one can memorize to differentiate between solvents which are part of the reaction and mechanism, and the ones that don’t affect the reactions at all? @TheRelentlessNucleophile

Comment: I doubt such a comprehensive guide exists. Yes, there are lists of solvents commonly used throughout organic chemistry (https://organicchemistrydata.org/solvents/) and other useful reagents and their purpose (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reagents). But predicting their exact behaviour and how they are going to impact the reaction is someting the chemist has to train themselves, through consistent exercise and studying the literature.

Comment: Chemistry is neither a set of easy rules, neither set of empirical knowledge to memorize. It is both, intertwined in a wild mixture of both extremes. Most non chemists are too impatient to recognize many patterns that are hybrids of rules and evidence. Chemistry is projection of very complex quantum interatomic relations to our macro world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct, the two numbered reagent and solvent pairs refer to *two* reactions, that will be done one after the other.

There is an intermediate product that can be isolated, or at least identified.